# What's the meaning of "staring into the Ark of the Covenant" as a analogy?

Tags: analogy

Like in here, to describe something horribly ugly?

> So Microsoft purchased a bit of middleware and fashioned it into
>   Direct3D Version 3. It was **universally reviled**. And with good reason;
>   looking at D3D v3 code is like **staring into the Ark of the
>   Covenant**.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/why-do-game-developers-prefer-windows

Comment: It melts your face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Bible, looking into the Ark of the Covenant means divine retribution, usually in the form of death.

> [**1 Samuel 6:19**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%206:19&version=KJV):
>   *And he smote the men of Bethshemesh, because they had looked into the ark of the Lord, even he smote of the people fifty thousand and threescore and ten men...*

(I found this quote [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/4106/27759) at Movies.SE, in reference to the film *Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark*, in which the Ark of the Covenant appears as a real artefact with great power.)

Comment: +1  That’s the reference, alright, but I think “according to Christian belief” is a bit strong.

Comment: @Jim Fair enough; edited.

Comment: Not sure what you would use instead of  “according to Christian belief” - after all it is part of Christian mythology.

Comment: Just to add: ***looking at D3D v3 code is like staring into the Ark of the Covenant.*** is fairly over-the-top language, and I would probably dismiss it altogether. Some of those coding types can get a bit full of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The physical ark of the covenant, as written within the bible, has a description that sounds far from "ugly". The ark itself was a chest, carved of fine wood and inlaid with gold. Inside of the Ark were the tablets of the Ten Commandments, a jar of manna, and Aaron's Rod that budded (Heb. 9:4). It served as the symbol of the very presence of God. To capriciously look within it, as a mere object of curiosity, would have been an act of disrespect to God himself then and the reasoning for divine retribution.

All of that being said, I would say that the phrase "looking at D3D v3 code is like staring into the Ark of the Covenant" is only a reference to the speaker's self-assessment that he suffered and metaphorically died trying to read it.

As stated by Cargill, it appears to be nothing more than an over the top expression.